# How to sort numbered filenames in list in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I try to sort a list that contains filepaths.
And I want them to be sorted by the numbers in them.

With the given code I use I don't get the expected result.

```
var mylist = mylist.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(Regex.Replace(x, "[^0-9]+", "0"))).ToList<string>();
```

I expect the result to be:

```
c:\somedir\1.jpg
c:\somedir\2.jpg
c:\somedir\3.jpg
c:\somedir\7.jpg
c:\somedir\8.jpg
c:\somedir\9.jpg
c:\somedir\10.jpg
c:\somedir\12.jpg
c:\somedir\20.jpg
```

But the output is random.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. It must have the `Main()` method as an entry point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Natural Sort Order in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp)

Comment: This works for me, apart from the redefinition of the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple way of achieving that.
Let's say you have a string list like this:

```
List<string> allThePaths = new List<string>()
{
    "c:\\somedir\\1.jpg",
    "c:\\somedir\\2.jpg",
    "c:\\somedir\\20.jpg",
    "c:\\somedir\\7.jpg",
    "c:\\somedir\\12.jpg",
    "c:\\somedir\\8.jpg",
    "c:\\somedir\\9.jpg",
    "c:\\somedir\\3.jpg",
    "c:\\somedir\\10.jpg"
};
```

You can get the desired result with this:

```
List<string> sortedPaths = allThePaths
    .OrderBy(stringItem => stringItem.Length)
    .ThenBy(stringItem => stringItem).ToList();
```

Note: Also make sure you've included LINQ:

```
using System.Linq;
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z4gLHJ) is a demo example just in case it's needed.

More complex solutions can be found [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp).

Comment: In this case `8.jpg` will come before `01.jpg`. may work here but in general there is a chance to fail.

Comment: Agreed, there is a chance. But I guess in that case `8.jpg` will instead be named `08.jpg` ;). Anyway, I've added a link to the answer for more complex solutions.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way of doing this would be to use `System.IO.Path`:

```cs
public IEnumerable<string> OrderFilesByNumberedName(IEnumerable<string> unsortedPathList) =>
    unsortedPathList
    .Select(path => new { name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path), path }) // Get filename
    .OrderBy(file => int.Parse(file.name)) // Sort by number
    .Select(file => file.path); // Return only path
```